# Modal opens on wrong position only the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

The first time, the modal opens partially out of the window but if I close and open again it opens on the right position.

```
<div id="modal-scores-grade" class="ui modal hide" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="header">Lançar nota</div>
    <div id="revision_type1" ng-show="current_score_index == 1">
        <div class="criteria-title">Critério 1</div>
        <div class="ui divider"></div>
        <div class="content wrapper-modal-grades">
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input name="norma_culta_radio" ng-init="revision.pt_norma_culta = 0" ng-model="revision.pt_norma_culta" type="radio" value=0>
                    norma culta
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="ui divider"></div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input name="norma_culta_radio" ng-model="revision.pt_norma_culta" type="radio" value=40>
                    norma culta 2
                </label>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui buttons">
                <div class="ui button closeScoreModal" ng-click="closeScore()">Fechar</div>
                <div class="ui positive button" ng-click="saveScore(2)">Salvar</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="revision_type2" ng-show="current_score_index == 2">
        <div class="header criteria-title">Critério 2</div>
        <div class="ui divider"></div>
        <div class="content wrapper-modal-grades">
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input name="entendimento_radio" ng-init="revision.pt_entendimento = 0" ng-model="revision.pt_entendimento" type="radio" value="0">
                    entendimento
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="ui divider"></div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>
                    <input name="entendimento_radio" ng-model="revision.pt_entendimento" type="radio" value="40">
                    entendimento 2
                </label>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <div class="ui buttons">
                <div class="ui button closeScoreModal" ng-click="closeScore()">Fechar</div>
                <div class="ui positive button" ng-click="saveScore(3)">Salvar e ir para Critério 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: As far as i know,only English is allowed here.

Comment: @Varun It's just the code wrap which is bad, i edited it, and will be approuved soon probably. The other language (spanish maybe, I don't know) is a part of his/her code

Comment: You'll have to post the code of your open / close modal functions - and possibly the css - if you want help.

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net